# Unable to get desired output in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project report which requires some tricky output from a single table.

This is the structure of the table named: **daily_visit_expenses**
[image: daily_visit_expenses]

having data like this::
[image]

now what i want the output is the combination of these three queries in a single column (any name), the queries are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_1`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_1`='Sales'
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_2`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_2`='Sales'
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_3`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_3`='Sales'
```

---

I want to get the output from a single query which is the combination of above three queries in a single column like `customers` which is `DISTINCT`.

SQL Export:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `daily_visit_expenses` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cust_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cust_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cust_3` text NOT NULL,
  `cust_4` text NOT NULL,
  `purpose_1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `purpose_2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `purpose_3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `purpose_4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `visit_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `expenses` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

INSERT INTO `daily_visit_expenses` (`id`, `user`, `date`, `status`, `location`, `cust_1`, `cust_2`, `cust_3`, `cust_4`, `purpose_1`, `purpose_2`, `purpose_3`, `purpose_4`, `visit_type`, `expenses`) VALUES
(5, 'sanjay', '2012-06-15', 'Working', 'Customer', 'S.G.R.S. Chemical & Minral Industries', '', 'fatehpur foundry', '', 'Sales', '', 'Sales', '', 'Outstation', 2323),
(8, 'sanjay', '2012-06-25', 'Working', 'Office', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0),
(9, 'sanjay', '2012-06-09', 'Working', 'Office', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0),
(10, 'sanjay', '2012-06-05', 'Working', 'Customer', 'V.N INTERNATIONAL', 'G.SURGIWEAR', '', '', 'Sales', 'Sales', '', '', 'Outstation', 332),
(11, 'sanjay', '2012-06-30', 'Working', 'Customer', 'Ganesh Plywood-Sitapur', '', '', '', 'Service', '', '', '', 'Outstation', 434),
(12, 'sanjay', '2012-06-04', 'Absent', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0),
(13, 'sanjay', '2012-06-06', 'Absent', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0),
(14, 'sanjay', '2012-06-08', 'Leave', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0);
```

Comment: Can you provide a dump.sql file I could use to create / populate a similar table on my end so I can test my query?

Comment: @sberry: added the sql dump...

Comment: Have you tried any `UNION` query? Even an `UNION ALL` between two different `SELECT` queries should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_1`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_1`='Sales'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_2`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_2`='Sales'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_3`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_3`='Sales';
```

Edit: Changed to UNION DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(`customer`) FROM ( SELECT `cust_1` as `customer` FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_1`='Sales' UNION ALL SELECT `cust_2` as `customer` FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_2`='Sales' UNION ALL SELECT `cust_3` as `customer` FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_3`='Sales') as t;
+---------------------------------------+
| customer                              |
+---------------------------------------+
| S.G.R.S. Chemical & Minral Industries |
| V.N INTERNATIONAL                     |
| G.SURGIWEAR                           |
| fatehpur foundry                      |
+---------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think that's what you need if i didn't misunderstood your question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`customer`) FROM
(
SELECT `cust_1` FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_1`='Sales' UNION ALL
SELECT `cust_2` FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_2`='Sales' UNION ALL
SELECT `cust_3` FROM `daily_visit_expenses` WHERE user='sanjay' AND `purpose_3`='Sales')
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`cust_1`,`cust_2`,`cust_3`) FROM `daily_visit_expenses`  
WHERE user='sanjay' AND (`purpose_1`='Sales' OR `purpose_2`='Sales' OR 
`purpose_3`='Sales' )
```